# Validate a value in property

Tags: c#, dry, encapsulation

So I heard that validating a value in a property like this:

```
//dummy example, let's assume that I want my value without dots
public string MyProp
{
    set
    {
        if(value.Contains('.'))
            throw new ArgumentException("Must not contain '.'", "value");
    }
}
```

is wrong and I should avoid it.

But in earlier days I was told that this is the good way. We could use encapsulation, there is just one place to check, DRY, etc.

What's wrong with my little example?

Comment: nothing wrong with it, but a) I'd rather throw an `ArgumentException`, b) you forgot to actually set the value!

Comment: You can't just throw a string.  You need to throw an exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# add validation on a setter method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127290/c-sharp-add-validation-on-a-setter-method)

Comment: @jrummell not duplicate. In that question they don't discuss exceptions

Comment: That is the good way. Several parts of the .NET framework do the same thing.

Comment: @caerolus both questions are about validating properties, so I disagree.

Comment: I agree with @caerolus, my concern is about validade data inside a prop so that question answered my.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with throwing exceptions in a property setter. But you should throw an `ArgumentException`, and also actually set the value of the property!

```
private string _myprop;
public string MyProp{
    set{
       if(value.Contains('.')) throw new ArgumentException("Must not contain .");
       this._myprop=value;
    }
    get { return this._myprop; }
}
```

From an [article on best practices in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006.aspx):

> Property getters should be simple operations without any preconditions. If a getter might throw an exception, consider redesigning the property to be a method. This recommendation does not apply to indexers. Indexers can throw exceptions because of invalid arguments.
>
> **It is valid and acceptable to throw exceptions from a property setter.**

Comment: Thanks! Actually was simple example for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

There  are  some similar questions also on SO.

You properities should be a lightweight as possible. And if setters throws an error this is ok but again you might consider moving it to a function. Things can get messy easily.

> AVOID throwing exceptions from property getters. Property getters
>   should be simple operations and should not have preconditions. If a
>   getter can throw an exception, it should probably be redesigned to be
>   a method.

[Best practices: throwing exceptions from properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488472/best-practices-throwing-exceptions-from-properties)

[What exception to throw from a property setter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633944/what-exception-to-throw-from-a-property-setter)

Answer (score -2):

Please see: [Best practices: throwing exceptions from properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488472/best-practices-throwing-exceptions-from-properties) for an explanation and discussion on why throwing exceptions from properties is bad.

Admittedly that post speaks about property getters.

Setters are generally seen by consumers as simply setting a private field hidden by the property and maybe doing some additional stuff as required, exceptions are unexpected behaviour and could you imagine having to enclose each set statement inside a try block?

While it may be accepted behaviour by guideline, it's a nightmare for guessing for developers, and validation logic should be contained in a separate method and then called from the property if need be.

If you need the validation or special behaviour when setting properties you should use a set method e.g. `SetMyProp(string value)` as it brings a distinction to it that it may lead to an exception etc.

If you're using the properties for something like a WPF model then you should make use of WPF's built-in validation for data instead.

Comment: -1 the very article you link to states that exceptions in **setters** are ok. From MSDN: "It is valid and acceptable to throw exceptions from a property setter."

Comment: Do you see a problem with a setter doing validation (and throwing an exception) to enforce it's contract (for example not allowing a null value to be set)?

Comment: @hatchet yes, I think for null values it's acceptable or for edge cases where the value *really* mustn't take on a certain form, but if it's a value that is "wrong" in the context of further use, the exceptions should take place when they're attempted to be used.

Comment: Why guess when you have docstrings? And your point of having a `try` block around every set statement is akin to using a `try` block around every `Substring` because your starting index could be out of bounds. Just check the data.

Comment: I disagree. It's perfectly acceptible for setters to throw exceptions. How else will you handle for example a property which is not allowed to be null? If you remove the setter, serialization will fail. The ability to do `Contract.Requires(value != null);` is essential.